# SimpleDateFormat Syntax with Apache-Poi

Tags: apache-poi

I am trying to get my excel tab named the day of the week to no avail.  I get the message 
*unable to resolve class SimpleDateFormat* when I attempt the code below.  Can anyone point me to my error and how to resolve it?

```
def dow = new Date()
def tab1 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE").format(dow)

Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook()

try {
Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet(tab1)
```

Comment: Did you import the SimpleDateFormat class? `import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;`

Comment: Dang! That was too easy @akokskis, I truly appreciate you.